# Locomotion-system with irregular IK

Tags: unity, assets

Im having some trouble with locomtions (Unity3D asset) IK feet placement. I wouldn't call it "very bad", but it definitely isn't as smooth as the Locomotion System Examples.

The strangest behavior (that is probably linked to the problem) are the rendered foot markers that "guess" where the characters next step will be. In the demo, they are smooth and stable. However, in my project, they keep flickering, as if Locomotion changed its "guess" every frame, and sometimes, the automatic defined step is too close to the previous step, or sometimes, too distant, creating a very irregular pattern.

The configuration is (apparently)Identical to the human example in the demo, so I guessing the problem is my model and/or animation. Problem is, I can't figure out was it is =S

Has anyone experienced the same problem? I uploaded a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jR9OYhB-ZQ) of the bug to help interpreting the issue (excuse the HORRIBLE quality, I was in a hurry).

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Use Fixed Update" checkbox in *CharacterMotor*, as shown in [this image](http://s018.radikal.ru/i526/1202/b2/1ffecbfe746e.jpg).